# Downgrading to a different version of Node

Tags: node.js

I accidently upgraded my Node server and it broke some stuff.

I'm using robot-js that only supports these versions of node - https://github.com/Robot/robot-js-binaries/tree/gh-pages/addon/1.0.2

How do I erase my current version and install the darwin-x64-14.node one?

I can't quite figure out the right command to install node-darwin-x64. What version do I put in?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-darwin-x64#download

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

Comment: Hey @ScottStensland I'm trying to understand what command do I use to install that version.

Comment: keep in mind that npm always comes bundled together with node so focus on uninstalling then installing node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) instead of directly installing `node.js` 
it allow me to change any version of node instantly.

you can find a detailed instruction of how to uninstall node [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/2147627).

then install nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

then to install a specific version of node just use

```
nvm install any-version
```

to change to a specific node installation

```
nvm use version
```

please for osx installation refer to the **Important Notes** section on their readme https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: ha, yea I don't understand what version it is? is it like a different type of node server? im so confused

Comment: i guess you are looking for `0.12.13` i just looked into https://github.com/Robot/robot-js-binaries/blob/gh-pages/addon/1.0.2/build_info.json and in the darwin i saw `"nodeVersion": "0.12.13"`

Comment: @MorganAllen NVM is a tool for managing versions of Node.js on your system. The version of NVM itself doesn't matter (in this case). Remove the node that is currently installed in the system and install NVM instead. Using NVM you'll be able to install (and change whenever you need) between different versions of node.js on your system (e.g. different versions of node for different projects).

Comment: this is weird. I got `0.12.13` installed but getting the error `SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.` which sounds like this was developed for `4.0.0` version of node or later? where can I see exactly what version of node it is expecting?

Comment: I figured it out! I downloaded and put the `nodedarwin-x64-48.node` file in the folder